# Debian Nginx and PHP Processor

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I know there is so much documentation about this but i can't understand where is the problem.
I have fresh installation of Debian 8 and the first think I install is Nginx fastcgi.
Nginx is working but it can't execute any php file.

i have tried some combination of section location ~ .php$ of nginx configuration file but when i try to load .php file from beowser it's just downloaded. There is the last try;

```
location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
           #fastcgi_index index.php;
           #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
           #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    }
```

where could be the problem?
Thx all

Comment: What result do you get? What do Nginx logs report?  Is the php-fpm service running?

Comment: that is the question, there is no errors :)
it just make me download any php file then i try to run them in browser

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by nothing work? If you get a error of type 500, then it may come from your nginx configuration. However if it is just that your php is not executed, it means that php-fpm service may not be running.

Comment: nothing work is about failure to execute php (it make me download php file), php-fpm is running. i think the problem is when nginx try to run php-fpm but i don't know why